# Using a Promises\A+ polyfill library in Jint, what alternatives to setTimeout do I have?

Tags: javascript, c#, jint

I am using an es6 Promises polyfill library ([es6-promise](http://es6-promise)) hosted in a [Jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) engine and for the most part, it is working well.

In order to have it work, I have needed to provide a `setTimeout` implementation and I took my inspiration from [how-to-create-timer-on-jint-javascript-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961918/how-to-create-timer-on-jint-javascript-side/34122607#34122607).

The use of this `setTimeout` implementation however is not faultless because there are occasions when the .NET Timer triggers the callback sooner than the Promises library completes its work in building in the Promise that is to be called back.

One remedy I have to solve this particular problem is to delay the `setTimeout` implementation and its execution of the callback; giving the library more time to complete its work. However, as the complexity of my javascript increases I find myself increasing the delay and I am seeking a reliable alternative.

It happens this library is itself concerned with alternatives. Its use of `setTimeout` is considered only when other alternatives cannot be found:  `process.nextTick()` for node; `BrowserMutationObserver` for webkit; `vertxTimer` (for java?); `MessageChannel` for a web workers.

My question is, does Jint (could Jint) expose anything similar to these concepts that would allow me to execute a callback on the next occasion of the eventloop and remain synchronous, as opposed to the asynchronous calling of a .NET Timer?

Comment: please illustrate your exact problem. sounds like an x-y problem

Comment: An alternative question could be "What Promises\A+ libraries are there that work in Jint and scale well?", this is the root of my problem. However since the like of nodejs provides a solution to schedule callbacks on the next event loop, it's not a leap of the imagination that Jint might do so too, hence my approach at the question.